# What were the names of the main characters in 'The Programmed Man'

Tags: character-identification

The first science fiction book I remember reading was '[The Programmed Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Sutton#The_Programmed_Man_.281968.29)' by Jean Sutton (I had to resort to google to remember the author). The wikipedia is light on the plot. It has the N-bomb which I forgot but not the reason the book was named the programmed man which I do remember but  I won't spoil in case anyone can find the book and wants to read. My question is what were the names of the main characters:

- the name of the detective who works for the government of the federated worlds
- the name of the teleport the detective is chasing
- there may have been a third character the main character narrates to

Comment: Daniel York is the name of the detective. Myron Terle was the teleport.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Daniel York; Myron Terle (I assume you know the plot-twist); and, Capt. Corden Hull seems to be who he speaks to the most, but I don't see a narration.

Comment: Thank you. It's been a really long time since I read. I believe you are correct on the Capt. I know the surprise ending was in a conversation with someone as they reached earth orbit. I thought maybe alot of the book was flashback from that conversation but couldn't remember.

Answer (score 1):

The book also follows August Karsh and Golem Gregory and their assistants, the two spymasters behind Daniel York and Myron Terle, respectively. The use of third person enables Jean and Jeff Sutton to easily follow multiple characters' points of view. The story wasn't told in a flashback from that final conversation that reveals the twist. It leads up to it.

Other characters on the ship with Daniel York are well represented and given important roles in solving the mystery at hand.

I bought a used copy because it was a childhood favorite. The absence of women makes it seem a little dated but still a well written book of its era.